# how to create a chest on client side?

Tags: smart-contracts, encrypted

Trying to build onchain guessing game using commit-reveal pattern pattern uses encryption, solidity example is

```
// Check the hash to ensure the commitment is correct
require(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, choice, blindingFactor)) == commitChoice.commitment, "invalid hash");
```

From previos stack exchange answers ı found that tezos doesnt have encryption in smart contracts. Instead using timeclock/chests.

the problem is how I can create a chest in client side ? only code I found is in OCaml

note: can't open approite tags due to low reputation

Comment: You have a few examples here: https://github.com/RomarQ/tezos-timelock#generate-chest-and-chest-key.

Comment: @RodrigoQuelhas thats exactly what I was looking for please post it as answer so I can accept,  ty spent hours looking for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few examples here : https://github.com/RomarQ/tezos-timelock#generate-chest-and-chest-key